# Boost convertor design query

Tags: pcb-design, boost

hi there i have designed a boost convert and want to check that it will work before i make it. It will have an input voltage of 200mv and pretty much no current (as the input is coming from a tree) and hopefully output anything higher.

[image: boost convertor schematic]

[image: boost convertor pcb]

I used Kicad to make the PCB and schematic.

Comment: "...the input is coming from a tree" what!?

Comment: Read the relevant patents: http://www.futurity.org/plug-in-to-a-low-voltage-tree/  Measuring biological voltage output and deriving power from said voltages is a research direction.

Comment: @JackCreasey I've never heard of that before. It is exceptionally unlikely that the asker will be able to do anything with discrete components, though. Much too lossy given the extremely low powers involved; you'd need custom-made ICs.

Comment: http://cds.linear.com/docs/en/datasheet/31081fb.pdf is a good starting point

Comment: You need to be much more specific about "pretty much no current". What's the short circuit and open circuit current of a tree? Or what's the output impedance of a tree? Also, your PCB layout has huge lossy components and teeeny thin traces. Probably won't work.

Answer (score 1):

Your circuit as shown is unlikely to work at all.
Since the power available is in the uW at voltages less than 500 mV, I can think of no BJT circuit that would allow a solution.

Perhaps you should start by reading this: http://wireless.ee.washington.edu/wp-content/uploads/sites/17/2013/03/NanoPerceptions2010.pdf

I suggest you investigate power conversion for metal thermopile generators (these produce the right voltage range, but much higher currents) where there are some viable circuits based on FET's such as [this](http://www.google.com/patents/US4734658). You could even revisit the [FET based Joule Thief](http://www.edn.com/design/power-management/4438702/MOSFET-based-Joule-Thief-steps-up-voltage) for ideas, though the losses would probably swamp any viability.

Comment: i may be able to find a tree that can produce just over 500mv and ive heard of companys such as voltree which have gotten around 1.1 volts

Comment: The low voltage is perhaps a surmountable problem....but the high output impedance I fear will kill almost any solution. Perhaps you could try using a Supercap or larger value ceramic capacitor to accumulate energy over several hours and then get a burst of conversion energy from the capacitor. 
The real challenge is to get an ultra high impedance level detector.